# Remove the gray bar at the bottom of view controller - iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

The image shows the View controller and the bar I want to remove. And also the structure of the view controller:

[image]

Someone told me how to remove the grey bar present at the bottom of the view controller as shown in the image. Unable to select and delete the bar. When I try to add the tab bar in that place, it goes behind the grey bar and becomes invisible.

Comment: You cannot "add a tab bar". You are not the child of a tab bar controller (are you?). What harm is this bar doing you in the storyboard? Does it appear when you run the app?

Comment: It creates an empty white space.

Comment: You'll probably need to use a different kind of view controller. I don't think that bottom bar is removable in a table view.

Comment: It's a view controller with table view in it, not a tableview controller. What type of other views controller I can use??

Comment: or the only solution left is to make the whole view from scratch.

Comment: But the table view's bottom is up to _you_. If there is a space at the bottom, it's because your constraints are wrong. You have not explained how you have determined the constraints of your table view.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What do your simulated metrics look like?

[image]

Can you get rid of the bar by changing the bottom setting?

Comment: Thanks, Lizza. It worked. You saved me a lot of time.

Answer (score 1):

This is a toolbar that comes with the `UINavigationController` that the View Controller is embedded in. Assuming you have a Navigation Controller on the storyboard connected to the view controller, select it and in the attributes inspector deselect "Shows Toolbar". If you want to do this in code you can get and set `isToolbarHidden` on a `UINavigationController` instance.

Comment: My class is --
class Home: UIViewController,UISearchBarDelegate,UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate,UISearchResultsUpdating, CustomSearchControllerDelegate{....

Comment: But your UIViewController is embedded inside a UINavigationController.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things - if you are using autolayout, just make a constraint to the bottom of the container, with 0 value for the constraint.  That will take it to the bottom.  Second thing I would add is a zero size table view footer to the tableview.